# ¿Cómo construir un número índice a partir de variaciones sobre una serie en R?

Tags: r

Tengo la siguiente variable que con una variación mensual, a partir de la cual necesito obtener un número indice donde la primera observación sea el número base (del `día` igual a 1).

```
dia <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
variacion <-  c(NA,  0.305,  0.285,  0.142)

df <-  data.frame(dia, variacion)
```

Necesito una nueva variable `X` que se construya como un índice a partir de la variable `variacion`, es decir:

```
   dia   variacion    X
1   1     NA          1
2   2     0.305       1.305
3   3     0.285       1.679
4   4     0.142       1.917
```

Intenté con

```
df %>% 
   mutate(X = case_when(dia == 1 ~ 1, 
                        T ~ NA), 
          X = lag(X) + lag(X) * variacion)
```

Pero no me dio resultado, dado que sólo me afectó al valor del dia 2, mientras que al resto los dejó como NA.

Desde ya se agradece la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Por ahora no llego a ver como resolverlo directamente con `dplyr` tengo la impresión que no hay forma de hacerlo, por que necesitarías acumular sobre una variable calculada secuencialmente, habría que investigar por el lado de proceso mediante `rowwise()`. Mientras tanto una aproximación más tradicional sería algo así:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if(is.na(df$variacion[row])) {
    acumulado <- 1
  } else {
    acumulado <- c(acumulado, acumulado[row-1] + acumulado[row-1] * df$variacion[row])
  }
}
df$X <- acumulado
df

  i dia variacion        X
1 1   1        NA 1.000000
2 2   2     0.305 1.305000
3 3   3     0.285 1.676925
4 4   4     0.142 1.915048
```